# How to play multiplayer game modes in single-player?

Tags: garrys-mod

For testing purposes, I would like to run Deathrun maps in single-player, with the event triggering, etc. working. How does one do this? I changed the game mode and map, but events aren't triggering, and I spawn with no weapons and the default health thingy in the bottom left.

How can I play multiplayer game modes in single-player?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about running a local multiplayer game with a low player count? (to prevent others from joining) That should make the gamemode behave as usual, without the extra people.

(You can probably create a server through the Multiplayer menu.)

Comment: By doing that, I get a lot of LUA error's in console, and saying a lot of error saying "Local file is overriding addon's file!" with the path to a lua file behind it, and the server is launching in the same way as it would by starting in Singleplayer.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you can go into singleplayer, select map, and do multiplayer on the top and select 0 players or 1. This works for version 13.